# Обработка json и php

Tags: json, php

Я не очень знаком с пхп, но серверная часть написана на нем. Вообщем я отправляю json такого типа на сервер:

```
{"tasks",TasksArray}
{"subtasks",SubTaskArray}
```

TasksArray и SubTaskArray  это JSONArray,

мне нужно как-то распарсить этот json чтоб потом заполнить данными таблицы в бд на сервере, в которых такие же столбцы, как и у принимаемых json массивов. то есть у TasksArray ключевые поля соответствуют столбцам таблицы tasks, и так далее. Можно ли это сделать элегантно не зная какие столбцы в таблицы и какие ключи в json? Если нельзя, то вот поля этих таблиц: 
tasks(_id,name)
subtask(_id,name,task_id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, используете функцию [json_decode()][1]. На выходе получите ассоциативный массив или объект, в зависимости от значения параметра **assoc**. Дальше можно поступить таким образом:

```
$arr = array(
    'tasks' => array(
        'firstname'=>'Петя',
        'secondname'=>'Петров',
    ),
    'subtasks' => array(
        'firstname'=>'Ваня',
        'secondname'=>'Иванов',
    ),
);
$query = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($arr as $table => $data){
    $query[$i] = "INSERT INTO `".$table."` SET ";
    $tmp = array();
    foreach($data as $field => $val){
        $tmp[] = "`".$field."` = '".$val."'";
    }
    $query[$i] .= implode(', ', $tmp);
    $i++;
}
```

В переменной $query, будет находится одномерный массив с запросами:

```
Array
(
    [0] => INSERT INTO `tasks` SET `firstname` = 'Петя', `secondname` = 'Петров'
    [1] => INSERT INTO `subtasks` SET `firstname` = 'Ваня', `secondname` = 'Иванов'
)
```

Вы, **конечно же**, уже не используете устаревшее расширение mysql_*, а пользуетесь MySQLi или PDO. Поэтому, вместо подстановки значений в цикле, ставите плейсхолдер, а данные собираете в массив, аналогичный $query с учетом плейсхолдеров и запросов, к которым они относятся.
[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Очень благодарен за ответ. Можете пожалуйста рассказать про mysqli, потому что у меня везде просто mysql. В чем будут проблемы? Трудно ли все поменять на mysqli.

Comment: Пересказать в двух словах не получится. Читайте документацию по [MySQLi][1] и [PDO][2]. В инете полно информации и примеров по этим расширениям, как например, [эта обзорная статейка][3]. Перейти на них достаточно легко, а сложнее сломать старую привычку. Не нужно "дрейфить", за день-два разберетесь.

   [1]:http://ua2.php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php
   [2]:http://ua2.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php
   [3]:http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/

Comment: а это очень критично, стоит ли это обязательно делать или в 80% случаев это не нужно?

Comment: @Jenya  Kirmiza, с моей т.з. критично.

Comment: так как же все-таки распарсить json. допустим я сделал json_decode($data) что я получил в итоге? как обратится к нему, чтоб заполнить данные в предложеный вами массив?

Comment: я думаю так но не уверен $json=json_decode($data)
$array=($data->{"tasks"})
$array[]
?

Comment: @Jenya Kirmiza, я показал вариант, если бы после преобразования, вы бы получили ассоциативный массив.

    $arr = json_decode($data, true);

Выведите на экран переменную **$arr** (*var_dump($arr) или print_r($arr)*), чтоб посмотреть результат и убедиться в корректном преобразовании.

Comment: я имел в виду, что писать вместо Петрова, Иванова?