# получение данных из другого сайа

Tags: php, javascript, json

Привет друзя 
нужно парсить осюда https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker 
на свой сайт

нужно вывести на сайт цифры [image: http://joxi.ru/BA0jXoecBwo0Qm]

с парсингом раньше не сталкивался расскажите как это реализовать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Обработка json и php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/333595/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-json-%d0%b8-php)

Comment: мне нужно брать данные из другого сайта

Comment: `curl` вам в помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = file_get_contents('https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker ');
$json = json_decode($str,1);

echo $json['USD']['15m'];
```